# Is there a way to preview SVG files in Adobe Bridge?

Tags: svg, adobe-bridge, cs2

I am not able to preview SVG files in Adobe Bridge since CS2 version.

Has Adobe removed this feature or am I missing something? I'm using both Windows and Mac, version CC and CS6.

Comment: Unfortunately, the feature was [removed in CS4](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2355777).

Comment: The importance of SVG in webdesign grows every year. Many people create layouts in Photoshop and therefore use Bridge to load their icons. Most icons you can buy come in SVG. Don't understand why Adobe does not see this. So please Adobe, it is 2016 and yes, it is time to correct this.

Comment: A lack of SVG preview support ultimately defeats the purpose of Bridge for me.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to Yisela for letting us know it was removed as a feature in CS4.

There are some alternative programs out there that accomplish this like [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) on Windows which also does a wonderful job at displaying .psd files as well.

It turns out on Mac OS there is a product made by Adobe that allows svgs as well appropriately called [Adobe SVG Viewer](http://download.cnet.com/Adobe-SVG-Viewer-OS-X/3000-2378_4-10117290.html). I can't speak to its efficacy, but it appears to be the alternative to Bridge for a Mac made by Adobe themselves.

Comment: Adobe plan on implementing SVG preview support in the future: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2230884

Answer (score 5):

I just found [SVG Viewer Extension for Windows Explorer](https://svgextension.codeplex.com/) that so far seems to work very well (in my case in Windows 10).

[image]

Comment: works great (tested on Win 10)

Answer (score 1):

If you check "**Include XMP**" on saving SVG dialog, you can get a preview, but it will bump filesize up like 10x times.

Tested on last Bridge CC version on Mac OS X 10.10

[image: SVG Options Save Dialog]

Comment: for all versions?

Comment: @Kurt I've tested it on last Bridge CC on Mac OS X 10.10. I suppose it will work on every version, since it using the same principle of using  XMP for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe has released a new update of Adobe Bridge (CC 2018) on 16 July 2018 with  support for SVG and PNG files, with transparency grid. The new version build number is 8.1.0.383.

This version is available to install via Adobe Creative Cloud application.